# Multivalue and single value lookup issue

Tags: list, lookup-column

Let's assume that we have two lists - `Foo` which has some kind of information - no matter what, and second - `Cities` - which holds city names.

Now, we set up on `Foo` list lookup field to `City` list and allow only single value for that lookup field. Scenario is this: I add item to `Foo` list and select `City` from lookup value. I save the item and I can see the city. Now I go to the `Cities` list and remove permissions for that list item for this user. When I go back to `Foo` list, I can see my previously added list item and empty lookup field. When I set up an filter for my lookup column to display items where lookup field is not empty, it works - item with lookup to city I don't have permissions to isn't shown.

But when we set up lookup in same manner as previously but allowing multiple values, this filter doesn't work. When I assign single value to this field from lookup list and remove permissions from that item in city list, I can see this item with empty lookup column in `Foo` list BUT I can't filter as before (saying that lookup field is empty). It looks like that there is always some value.

All in all, I'd like to filter out items in Foo list that have lookup value empty, but that doesn't work for multivalue lookup. I'd like to know where this issue comes from and if there is possibility to fix it.